# Laravel 5 WebPack JQuery - $ is not defined

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5, webpack, laravel-5.6

I Have webpack.min.js:

```
mix.webpackConfig(webpack => {
    return {
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: 'jquery',
                jQuery: 'jquery',
                'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
                Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
            })
        ]
    };
});

mix.sass('resources/assets/styles/index.scss', 'public/css/app.css')
    .js('resources/assets/scripts/index.js', 'public/js/app.js')
    .copyDirectory('resources/assets/static', 'public/static')
    .version()
    .sourceMaps();
```

and package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.7.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.24.6",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "datatables": "^1.10.18",
    "easy-pie-chart": "^2.1.7",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.9.0",
    "jquery-sparkline": "^2.4.0",
    "jvectormap": "^2.0.4",
    "laravel-mix": "^2.1.11",
    "load-google-maps-api": "^1.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "masonry-layout": "^4.2.2",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.1.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "skycons": "^1.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.16"
  }
```

and in my blade footer script:

```
@section('footer')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') { alert(jQuery.fn.jquery); }

        $(function() {
        $('#cc-number').validateCreditCard(function(result) {
            $('.log').html('Card type: ' + (result.card_type == null ? '-' : result.card_type.name)
                + '<br>Valid: ' + result.valid
                + '<br>Length valid: ' + result.length_valid
                + '<br>Luhn valid: ' + result.luhn_valid);
        });
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

after i run `npm run dev` and load my page, i receive error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

and my `alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);` is not triggered

how do i load jquery from npm so then i can use it at inline html code in blade?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this in your main.js file

```
global.$ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

Comment: which main.js file? in here: `resources/assets/scripts/index.js`?

Comment: anyway, adding `global.$ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');` in `resources/assets/scripts/index.js` solve the problem - Thanks!

Comment: For others finding this topic using Laravel 5.8: If you have a `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>` tag in your `app.blade.php`, just move it to the end of your `body` tag and remove the `defer` statement. This should solve the problem and still work fine with vue.js

Comment: ^ Underrated solution. I spent HOURS dicking around with adding `windows.$ =...` throughout my JS files, it was still not available in blade. THIS fixed it.

Answer (score 27):

in app.blade.php

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

remove defer so make it

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" ></script>
```

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17634#issuecomment-375473990

Comment: What is that `defer` for?

Comment: `defer` means that the script will only get loaded when everything else is loaded

Comment: landed here after wasting half a day to find the solution. Thanks, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 10):

I had this issue in Laravel 5.7 when I tried using some of the default views that it provided. I was trying to use JavaScript (which required using jQuery) in some blade view templates that extended the default `layout/app.blade.php template`.

But for me the problem **was not** the `window.$` not being assigned the window.jQuery library, because it was being added as far as the `resources/js/bootstrap.js` file was concerned. (This is a file that appears to be precompiled into `public/js/app.js` by Laravel Mix. You can see this is the case by looking into `webpack.mix.js`, within it, you'll find this statement:

`mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')`

where

`resources/js/app.js` requires `resources/js/bootstrap.js` .

If you wish to manually compile this for yourself first run:

`npm install` then `npm run dev` when in development mode, or `npm run prod` when in production mode.

### but anyways (I've digressed) ....

It turned out that the issue was here:

`resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php`

There was an instance of script tag with a defer attribute like so:

`<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>`

That `defer` attribute was causing all the problems.

So I removed it like so:

`<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>`

and the problem of jQuery not being defined was solved.

I prefer to defer my JavaScript loading by simply moving the script tags closer to the end of `body` HTML tag anyways.

Comment: that `defer` statment seems to be necessary if you use Vue.js. If you just move the `<script>` tag to the end of your `<body>` tag, it will work fine as well. Not sure why they put it up there

Comment: In my case it was causing problems, even if I had already put the script tag at the end of the body. What exactly is that `defer` for?

Answer (score 3):

I use mix.copy instead mix.js for jQuery and it works great!

example:

```
mix.copy('node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', 'public/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js');
```

Comment: Then add `<script src="{{ asset('vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>` before `</body>`