# Laravel Mix - can't use jQuery in template

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I use Laravel 5.6, I removed Vue.JS to use jQuery on my project. I can use jQuery in my JS files, but I can't use it in my template.

I created an yield to put Javascript, this yield is loaded at the end of the page.

I looked at `app.js` and `bootsrap.js` default files, it seems that jQuery is loaded in boostrap :

```
try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
```

I tried to define the global in my app.js :

```
let $ = require('jquery');
// create global $ and jQuery variables
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
```

And I put this in my webpack.mix.js :

```
mix.autoload({
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    $: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery'
});
```

I got no errors, I just can't use $ or jQuery in my blade templates, I have this message :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

In Symfony 4, I only put the global $ in app.js, and it works. What do I miss ?

My app.js :

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('./custom-checkboxes');

$(function() {
    $('body').click(function(e) {
        // it works
    });
});
```

My webpack.min.js :

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/pages/homepage.scss', 'public/css')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/pages/calendar.scss', 'public/css')
;
mix.autoload({
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    $: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery'
});

mix.copyDirectory('resources/assets/img', 'public/img');

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

My bootstrap.js :

```
window._ = require('lodash');
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;

/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}

....
```

Comment: Are you not using bootstrap?

Comment: I use bootstrap, it's required in my main `app.js`

Comment: The default code that comes with Laravel (the try/catch block) should allow jQuery to be available globally via the window object. Was that not the case for you? What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I use 5.6, I tried to use `window.$` in my template, but same error.

Comment: Do you have `window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;` at the top of your `bootstrap.js` file?

Comment: Yes, I tried to remove it, but the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177437/discussion-between-ross-wilson-and-vincent-decaux).

Comment: Did you fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What I did was remove the *defer* property from the script tag that refer to `app.js` file in the `app.blade` file and put that script tag to the bottom of the page.

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

change this to,

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

and add other js files(if needed) below it.
No need to configure any other files or add external reference to *jQuery* as [it loaded by *Mix*](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/frontend#writing-javascript).

you can check this out too.
[Laravel 5 WebPack JQuery - $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51595843/10856266)