# Laravel CRUD using Firebase

Tags: laravel, firebase, crud

I'm trying to implement Realtime CRUD using Google Firebase in my web application,I've managed to retrieve data from the Firebase Database but I saw an error while inspecting elements.

**Error:**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at users:37
```

I've tried all possible solutions, these made the error gone but I can't add/update/delete data. basically none of this work

***links:***

1. [ReferenceError: $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268881/referenceerror-is-not-defined/27545360)
2. [Laravel 5 WebPack JQuery - $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51595843/laravel-5-webpack-jquery-is-not-defined)
3. https://medium.com/@onwuka_gideon/fixing-laravel-jquery-is-not-defined-a316fd918e0a

I've followed every step on ***here:***

*note that I am using Laravel 5.8 rather than 5.6

https://laravelcode.com/post/laravel-56-realtime-crud-system-using-google-firebase#

You can recreate the problem by following it.

Comment: possibly you forget to include the jquery library.

Answer (score 2):

include `jQuery` before `firebase.js` i.e.

> recreated and worked as you mentioned in this [LINK](https://laravelcode.com/post/laravel-56-realtime-crud-system-using-google-firebase#)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.1/firebase.js"></script>
```

Example Repo - [GITHUB](https://github.com/coderatio/larafirebase.git)

Comment: no matter what i do it still doesn't go through. can I clone your project? and what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: replicated on local, and I used laravel 5.8